# Trouble designing a container box drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, dropdown

I'm pretty new to front end and I'm having trouble getting the desired outcome for this particular project. Not sure if this is right direction, but I'm using unnumbered lists for a drop down on hover and I'm displaying options horizontally.

The issue is that I want the drop down to take on different css than the main navigation bar so that I can create img links in the drop down formatted in a specific way (See picture drawn in illustrator vs blue bg color on hover in code). Is this possible with the current code that I have?

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried a variety of different drop down ideas and none of them seem to be able to trigger their own css.

```
<ul id="tnbmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
#tnbmenu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#tnbmenu {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
}
#tnbmenu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#tnbmenu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#tnbmenu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#tnbmenu li a {
    display:block;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    background-color: #273133;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:17px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#tnbmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #61BEC8;
    color: #273133;
    transition: background-color .2s ease;
}
#tnbmenu li ul li {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! It is often easier for us to help you, if you share a Fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I little change you have to do, to make your code, workable,
`display: inline-block` to `display: inline-flex`

```
#tnbmenu {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
}
```

```css
#tnbmenu, #menu ul {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#tnbmenu {
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 100%;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
}
#tnbmenu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
#tnbmenu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#tnbmenu > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#tnbmenu li a {
    display:block;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    background-color: #273133;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:17px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#tnbmenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #61BEC8;
    color: #273133;
    transition: background-color .2s ease;
}
#tnbmenu li ul li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<ul id="tnbmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop Down</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

let me know if I can help more with this !!

cheers :) Happy to help

Comment: Hey, it unfortunately did not. But I found a work around. I just had to target them differently. I ran the li and ul in reverse order targeting a class on the ul that had the drop down. So instead of " class li ul {} " I used "li ul class {}" and it seemed to workout.